# GetAsyncKeyState DLLImport statement

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I ran into a situation where I needed to change the DLL Import statement I was using depending on the OS.  I'm wondering if anyone else has observed this, knows why, or if there is a better way to handle this.

Here is a minimal code snippet showing the problem.  It is a simple command line app that just outputs the status of the shift key.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Shift
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(ushort virtualKeyCode);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shift is: " + GetAsyncKeyState(0x10));
        }
    }
}
```

The above works fine for me when ran on Windows 8.1 x64 or when built as 32-bits and run on Windows 7 x64.  It does not however work on a Windows 7 system when compiled for x64.  In that case GetAsyncKeyState always returns 0.

If I change the DLLImport to the following it then works on Windows 7 system when compiled for x64.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int virtualKeyCode);
```

Comment: The initial declaration had a bug. (ushort is 16 bits, int is 32 bits - on 32 and 64-bit OSes all versions of Windows). Anything can happen with a bug, including the illusion it works fine. So what's your question?

Comment: x64 has a very different calling convention, enabled by it having a lot more registers.  A fastcall style convention, the first 4 arguments are passed through registers instead of the stack.  x86 does not allow pushing 16 bit values onto the stack, so there is an implicit integer promotion.  Which hides the bug in the declaration.  The best way to declare this function is to use Keys as the argument type.  So you can pass Keys.ShiftKey, enums are nice.  It never hurts to compare with the pinvoke.net web site.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the very specific description of what is occurring.  That was the answer I was hoping to get.

Answer (score 2):

The original declaration is wrong. The documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293.aspx

This gives the declaration as:

```
SHORT WINAPI GetAsyncKeyState(
  _In_ int vKey
);
```

The correct p/invoke is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
```

Note that I have removed the setting of `SetLastError`. The documentation makes no mention of `SetLastError` being called.